# How to change the user-agent in react native fetch api

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I have tried to change the user agent in react native fetch API:

```
const URLENCODED_HEADER = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'User-Agent': Platform.OS + "/" + DeviceInfo.getUniqueID().toString()
}

export async function doRegister(secureInfo) {
  formBody = encodeParameters(secureInfo)
  try {
    let response = await fetch(SERVER_URL+'/user/register', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: URLENCODED_HEADER,
      body: formBody,
      credentials: 'include'
    });
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson;
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I have also checked the requests' header in Reactotron:
[image]

And it shows the correct information I want.

However, on the server side, the `ua` is still the default for android and ios devices:

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_2_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.5.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15D100 Safari/604.1`

`okhttp/3.6.0`

`Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; Coolpad 3622A Build/LMY47V)`

Is it possible to change the `user-agent` for requests sent in react-native and how if so?

Answer (score 3):

Try to `Stop Remote JS Debug` to test it.

I was dealing with the same problem too.
It worked for me. :)

Some notes:

1. it's only for React Native
2. React Native already has a default User-Agent. Something like: `<PROJECT_NAME>/<VERSION> CFNetwork/975.0.3 Darwin/17.7.0`
3. while using Remote JS Debugging, it'll use the browser user-agent. Something like: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36`

Comment: What is the solution ?

Comment: open the In-App developer menu (https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging) and disable `Stop Remote JS Debug`

Answer (score 1):

https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#configuring-nsurlsession-on-ios

For some applications it may be appropriate to provide a custom `NSURLSessionConfiguration` for the underlying NSURLSession that is used for network requests in a React Native application running on **iOS**. For instance, one may need to set a custom user agent string for all network requests coming from the app or supply `NSURLSession` with an emphemeral `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.